# iOS App Issue - Can't access image from image asset catalog

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiimageview

I'm new to iOS development, so apologies for advance. I know this has been covered earlier but I can't seem to find anything that helps with my issue.

Its a fairly simple but annoying issue.

I have a image in assets with a file name of hollwood.png but a xcode name, "hollywood" (no png).

I am trying to set a UIImageView to display it.

So in ViewDidLoad I have the following: (imageContainer is the UIImageView IBOutlet)

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
super viewDidLoad];

self.model = [Model sharedModel]; 

self.imageContainer.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"hollywood"];

}
```

I can not get it to display the image from Assets.
I know the `UIImageView` outlet works correctly because I can have the app choose a photo from gallery and set the photo to `UIImageView`.

I'm having a very difficult time figuring out how to load the image I saved in the assets catalog into `UIImageView`.

Comment: Can you verify if `imageContainer` is not `nil`? is it a `IBOutlet`?

Comment: imageContainer is an IBOutlet

Comment: Check your image names "hollwood.png" and you are using "hollywood".

Comment: "Hollywood.png" does not work, regardless Apple's documentation stated that only the name provided in the attributes for the image set needs to be called, not the file name.

Comment: Can you tell me the actual **File Name** and **ImageAssets Name**. Or did you solve the problem?

Comment: I'm having the same issue on one of my apps.  I just can't get it to load the images from the asset catalog.

Answer (score 1):

I just had this issue. I had dragged the image and for some reason Xcode added a weird "Design" locale and I couldn't load the image using UIImage(named: ). I don't know if this is your case, but you can try right clicking on the image in the Asset Catalog, "Show in Finder", opening the folder and checking the "Contents.json" file. Each image there should only have the keys "idiom", "filename" and "scale".

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your image is added in Compile Sources

AppTarget->Build Phases-> Compile Sources

If not try to add that and check.

Comment: I added the entire Image.xcassets file (wouldn't let me choose a photo individually). It still does not work.